# enter a string from the keyboard and check how many vowels are available and extarct the middle character of the string

Tags: java, loops, methods, drjava

The assignment asks that a method returns the value true if a given character is a vowel, and otherwise returns false. Then to test that method by asking the user for a String, and checking each characters of the String the user entered, returning true if vowel, and false if not. So far, I have created the method, and have created a loop to read through the String, but unfortunately it only checks the character the user initially inputted rather than the characters of the String.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Vowels{

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
char ch = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

boolean result = isVowel(ch);
System.out.println(result);

System.out.println("Please enter a String: ");
String str = keyboard.next();

boolean answer = isVowel(ch);
for(int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++){
  if(str.charAt(i) == ch){
    answer = true;
    System.out.println(answer);
  }
  else{
    answer = false;
    System.out.println(answer);
  }
 }
}

public static boolean isVowel(char ch){
boolean answer;
if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u'){
  answer = true;
  return answer;
}
else{
  answer = false;
  return answer;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you want to combine multiple boolean checks you should be using either the `&&` or `||` operators in your loop to combine the previous value of `answer` with the result of `isVowel` for the current character.  Try rephrasing your problem as "the first element has a property AND the second has that property" or "the first element has a property OR the second has a property" to figure out which is appropriate to your circumstances.

Comment: Thank you, Mike Samuel. That makes sense. I will take those changes highly into consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 if(str.charAt(i) == ch){
```

to

```
 if (isVowel(str.charAt(i)){
```

to check each character for being a vowel instead of checking each character for matching the 1st character you entered.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I was initially trying to use .equals, but that cannot be used on boolean or char expressions. I do have one final question, if Dr Java complains because "String index is out of range: 4," is that due to the length of the String?

Comment: That error message means you tried to get the 5th character out of a string that is less than 5 in length.

Comment: Which was due to <= equal sign... Fixed. Thank you for the input, you have been a great deal of help, Lee Meador.